# Docker - find base image info from child image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a remote repo with the images below

```
REPOSITORY         TAG                 IMAGE ID
base_image_1       latest              7686118f5df8
base_image_2       latest              60334caa78a6
base_image_3       latest              3a6104a523b0
child_image        latest              37a036064667
```

`child_image` was built using `base_image_*` using the `FROM` instruction like below

`FROM base_image_2:latest`

The `FROM` instruction and could have used any of `base_image_1`, `base_image_2` or `base_image_3`
I do not have the dockerfile of `child_image` to know which `base_image_*` was used.

I have pulled all the images to my local machine.
I want to know which `base_image_*` was used to build the `child_image`.
I searched for names, sha256, image IDs of `base_image_*` in the output of `docker inspect child_image:latest`, but could not find any info.

I tried `docker history child_image:latest`. It gave an output with all Image IDs as `<missing>` except the first one, which is the `child_image` itself.

```
docker history child_image:latest
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
7686118f5df8        29 hours ago        CMD ["node" "index.js"]                         0B                  buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>           29 hours ago        EXPOSE map[8505/tcp:{}]                         0B                  buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>           29 hours ago        ENV PORT=8505                                   0B                  buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>           29 hours ago        ENV NODE_ENV=production                         0B                  buildkit.dockerfile.v0
```

Is it possible to know which `base_image_*` was used to build `child_image`?

Comment: Each image is made of layers and you can verify that child_image contains all the layers of base_image_3. Base_image_3 contains all the layers of base_image_2. And so on. You can see the layers using the `docker history` command.

Comment: As [this answer](/a/67927907) notes, "The information doesn't really exist, exactly."  An image doesn't have the name of its base image recorded anywhere; it embeds the layers of its base and you might be able to use that to deduce what the base was.

Comment: @HansKilian I have updated the question with what happens when I use `docker history`.

Comment: @DavidMaze How do I use the layers info (I presume you meant using `docker inspect child_image:latest` ) to deduce the base image? Could you explain a bit.